# Why do my DateTime query results have such a huge offset?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have an SQLAlchemy column_property designed to get the latest eligible DateTime from a set of objects, modeled like so:

```
latest_released_date = column_property(
   select(
       Movie.release_date).where(
           Movie.release_date <= datetime.now(
               tz=timezone.utc)).order_by(
                   Movie.release_date.desc()).limit(
                       1).correlate_except(
                           Movie).scalar_subquery())
```

However it does not seem to return the most recent eligible DateTime, and instead returns null even when I have a set of objects with eligible DateTimes.

I manually created objects with datetimes further and further back in time, and I would hit a point where the column_property starts to return values, but sometimes a datetime would have to have an offset as large as 3 days in the past before the column_property would pick up on it.

I made sure to save all datetimes in UTC timezone, and my database and server are both set to UTC.

```
"release_date": "2022-12-16T11:36:46.974253" # doesn't show up as latest_released_date
"release_date": "2022-12-13T02:06:00" # does show up as latest_released_date
# results of checking tz.info, datetime.now() and datetime.utcnow()
"system_timezone": "UTC",
"now": "2022-12-17 02:45:08.911701",
"now_utc": "2022-12-17 02:45:08.911711+00:00"
```

Has anyone had this happen to them before, or know why it happens/how to fix it?

Comment: I don't understand the use of column_property here.  Isn't it supposed to be referencing the table somehow ?  I'm not sure what that query will actually do.

Comment: Is the column_property on the Movie class itself?

Comment: Also I think datetime.now() would be fixed at declaration time.  Maybe you just need a regular query to get this value and not column_property.

Comment: @IanWilson The column property is defined on another table (Series) which has child references to the Movie table, I accidentally missed the condition on the select part of it where Movie.series_id == id. The purpose of the column_property is basically to get the most recent release_date for Movies of the Series.

I think maybe it is an issue with the value being fixed at declaration time, however I need this latest_released_date as a dynamic property for each instance of a Series, is there some way to do that without resorting to separate queries?

Comment: Either way I think you've nailed the issue, if you want to leave a top level answer I can select it as the one and resolve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed the fact that datetime.now() would only be called once at declaration time, so it would always hold the value of when I deployed my server. I fixed it by switching to SQLAlchemy's built in func.now() instead in the column_property, and now everything works as expected.